# RTOS: Could not take the data for queue

Tags: memory, queue, stm32, freertos, rtos

I tried to get data form the queue

I create a heap memory to stored a data
`uint8_t *data6; // global`

```
status = xTaskCreate(print_task, "print_task", 250, NULL, 2, &handle_print_task);

  configASSERT(status == pdPASS);

  queue_print = xQueueCreate(20, sizeof(uint8_t *));
  data6 = pvPortMalloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * 50);
```

I received some data from Interrupt UART and put that into the array

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  if (huart->Instance == USART6)
  {

    if (count_size6 < 100)
    {
      data6[count_size6] = data_byte6;
      count_size6++;
      if (data_byte6 == '\n')
      {
        data6[count_size6] = '\0';
        xQueueSendFromISR(queue_print, &data6, NULL);
        count_size6 = 0;
        // memset(data6,0,sizeof(&data6));
      }
    }

    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart6, &data_byte6, 1);
  }
}
```

and the I take that form the task which created in the main code

```
//this is the task handler
void print_task(void *param)
{

    UBaseType_t free_spaces;
    uint8_t arr[10];
    uint8_t *msg;
    while (1)
    {

        if (xQueueReceive(queue_print, &msg, portMAX_DELAY) == pdPASS)
        {
            free_spaces = uxQueueSpacesAvailable(queue_print);
            sprintf((char *)arr, "Left: %u\n", (unsigned int)free_spaces);
            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, arr, 10, 1000);

            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, msg, 50, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
            vPortFree(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

But I checked the address of dynamic memory that had a right data. I aslo checkout the value when i take address for deqeue. But it did not has anything. How can I fix it. Please help me to understand what wrong with my code.Thank for caring

Comment: `uint8_t *data6;` just defines a pointer, it doesn't point to anything, least of all a 100-byte array. Unless you've allocated memory elsewhere and not shown us that part.

Comment: `xQueueCreate(20, sizeof(uint8_t *));` looks suspicious. Do you want a queue of 20 pointers? Likewise `xQueueSendFromISR(queue_print, &data6, NULL);` `&data6` is a constant that will never change.

Comment: Yah i created `data6 = pvPortMalloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * 50);`
i'll update on my post

Comment: Isn’t it better to check count_size6 < (sizeof(uint8_t) * 50) ? Also you can’t vPortFree the transferred pointer if you want to reuse the data6 buffer. Note that the data6 buffer might get changed by the ISR while you process the received msg.

Comment: So is it 50 bytes or 100 bytes? Maybe have a `#define` for the size of the buffer, and use that everywhere. I still think you have other problems with your queue. Your use of pointers seems very wrong.